# Disable Touch Event Intercept

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-touch-event

I have a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` and then a bunch of `TextViews` inside that layout, the goal is to make a `CustomListView` that will open and close various `TextViews` along the `LinearLayout` However, I also want to make an autoscroll feature where when the user double taps the screen the screen will scroll by its self.

I already have the second part done, when ever the user touches the `ScrollView` I have extended `ScrollView` and implemented this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("ScrollView Intercept", "ACTION_DOWN");
        return true;
    } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("ScrollView Intercept", "ACTION_UP");
        return true;
    } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        Log.d("ScrollView Intercept", "ACTION_CANCEL");
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Now the `ScrollView` has all the touch events.
However, I still want the events for the `CustomListView`, I have tried to implement a `equestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent` but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    Log.d("touch listner","Touch");
    return true;
}
```

PS. I have tried to se `ListView` in the past, but it was a but confusing so I just extended the `TextView` class and wanted to use on click and manually make the children `Visible` and `Gone`

Comment: You can use expandable listview. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried in another area of my project, but I couldnt get it to work, was a little complicated. also, I would have the same issue with the touch events